# Why variable still exists after function call finished -python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I read from a book about some code like below, but it was not explained.
As you can see, before I call the function, no variable exists. 
But after function call, var2 was popped form stack and removed from our namespace of func_a as what we expected. But, var1 still exists!!!

> How to explain this phenomenon? Is var1 a special kind of variable?

```
def func_a():
    func_a.var1 = 1
    var2 = 2

>>> func_a.var1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'var1'

>>> var2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'var2' is not defined

>>> func_a()
>>> func_a.var1
1
>>> var2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'var2' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4):

> How to explain this phenomenon? Is var1 a special kind of variable?

Yes, `var1` is a special kind of variable. Or perhaps more precisely, it's not a variable at all. It's an attribute of an object (even though the object is a function). The object existed before the function call, and it continues to exist after.

In the function call you are *adding an attribute* to a global object rather than *creating a variable* in a local scope.

Comment: I feel like, It's more like a class. An object shou be collected as bargage when its not being referenced by others, is it?

Comment: Yes, an object is garbage-collected when it is not being referenced. `var1` _is_ being referenced -- `func_a` has a reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the function namespace with the function object. Before the function is called, `var1` doesn't exist. When the function is called, python creates a temporary local namespace for that one call. When the function hits `var2 = 2`, `var2` is created in the local function namespace. When the function hits `func_a.var1 = 1`, python looks `func_a` up in the global namespace, finds the function object, and adds `var1` to it. When the function exits, the local namespace disappears but the function object still exists and so will `var1`.